# analyzing C++ code snippet (involving classes and functions)

Tags: c++

I'm a college student who just enrolled in a junior-level c++ course. I've never taken c++ before, only one C course about two years ago. Below I've pasted a homework problem I have to analyze tonight. I don't want you guys to answer it, just to give me some pointers on where to start. The problem I'm having is I don't know where to pass the variables that are declared in the problems. For example, the first problem I have to evaluate in the function is `large.getDiameter()`, but I have absolutely no clue where to start.

```
class Pizza {
private:
     double diameter;
     int slices;
     double area() { return (diameter/2)*(diameter/2)*3.14; }

public:
     bool sauce;  
     bool cheese; 
     bool pepperoni;

public:
     Pizza(double dia, 
           int nslice=8,
           bool has_sauce=true, 
           bool has_cheese=true, 
           bool has_pepp=true)
     {
           diameter = dia;
           slices = nslice;
           sauce = has_sauce;
           cheese = has_cheese;
           pepperoni = has_pepp;
     }
     int getSlices() { return slices; }
     double getDiameter() { return diameter; } 
     double areaPerSlice() { 
           return area() / slices;
     }
};
```

Consider these variables declared within a function:

```
Pizza large(16, 10);
Pizza personal(6, 4,true,true,false);
Pizza medium(12);
Pizza small(10.0,6);
```

Some examples of what I have to pass are:

```
1.)large.getDiameter()
2.)small.getDiameter()
3.)large.areaPerSlice() > small.areaPerSlice()
4.)personal.pepperoni
5.)medium.getSlices()
```

Comment: Could you possibly describe the problem in further detail. I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: you have to pass large.getDiameter(), small.getDiameter(), and medium.getSlices() into the above class definition and my professor wants you to say what the definition gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Your class Pizza has a constructor with some useful parameters (some with default arguments so you don't have to pass those).

When you create the Pizza ie by saying Pizza large(16, 10) you have already automatically passed in the diameter and slices.

So by using an accessor method such as pizza.getDiameter() you'll notice the code is already there to return what you passed into (and assigned to diameter) in your constructor.  The accessor method will return the desired number.  you could easily assign it to another vairable or use it directly as in the case of the comparison example.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, by calling large.getDiameter(), you are essentially passing (16, 10) into the function getDiameter(), but since it only returns diameter, it will just return 16?

Comment: large.getDiameter() isn't where you passed the diameter into the class, you passed the diameter into the class when you created it by saying Pizza large(16, 10). The Pizza constructor has the first parameter double dia where it accepts the number 10 as dia then in the constructor assigns dia to diameter. If you look at the code in getDiameter it simply returns that member variable.

Comment: Wait, why does dia accept 10 instead of 16? Since dia is the first variable declared in Pizza, and 16 is the first value passed, wouldn't dia be 16?

Comment: Sorry, 16, my mistake.

Comment: Oh okay, this is starting to make more sense, thank you so much! I do have another question though, if you were to pass large.diameter, would it return an error because that specific function is not declared in public?

Comment: Its private so you can't set it that way but what you can do is create a setter (similar to the getter you have). Look up getters/setters which would allow you to access those private members and change them.  Keep in mind you've already set the private member variable in the constructor.  A setter will only be useful if you want to change it.  The style your code has above seems that a setter will be the best way to go about it if you want to change the diameter - but logically, once a pizza is created how do you change its diameter?